# PHP Regex fails with '&' in string; passes (correctly) in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, regex

Running Linux (Ubuntu 11.10), the same regular expression works in JavaScript, but fails when `&` is included in the string being evaluated in PHP. Here's what I mean:

#### JavaScript regex:

```
regex = /^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ',.@&!+-]{3,50})$/;
```

#### PHP regex:

```
$settings['regex_name'] = "/^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ',.@&!+-]{3,50})$/";
```

When the code runs in a browser to verify a string (for example `D & L Auto Sales`), JavaScript matches the entire string as it should. However, when the server-side code attempts to match on the same string, it fails.

Has anyone run into this before?

EDIT:
This is the PHP code that runs the regex:

```
function validated_array(&$array) {
    global $settings;

    $filterDefinitions = array( "name" => array('filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
                                'options' => array('regexp' => $settings['regex_name']),
        ...
    );


    $retVal = filter_var_array($array, $filterDefinitions);
```

When the code runs with `D & L Auto Sales`, $retVal['name'] is empty. However, when I remove the `&`, $retVal['name'] has a value.

Comment: As a general rule you can't assume that regular expressions will work identically in every scripting/programming language. In your case, I'm assuming there are different escape character requirements.

Comment: Works for me using `preg_match()`. How are you executing the regex match?

Comment: I've added the PHP code above.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted? Would it have helped if I had linked to http://us3.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the `&` is not encoded as `&amp;` in your HTML ?

Otherwise, Perl Compatible Regular Expressions have a high rate of compatibility between JavaScript and PHP (supported by both), and especially the one you gave in your example.

Comment: This is close enough to the problem: "name" comes from the URL, and it is decoded (turning &amp; into &) for use in most of the javascript, so when I reuse the value in an ajax query, the & truncates the name short enough to fail validation. Thanks!

Comment: @JoBu1324 No worries. Glad you figured it out.